# Native functions for Multidimensional Array Matching in Android / Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, matrix

Are there any native functions to use for multidimensional array matching in Android/Java -- or is the only way to match an array to use nested for loops N times for an N-serialized/dimensional  array?

```
dice1[]={1,1,1,1,1,1};
dice2[]={0,0,0,1,1,1};
dice3[]={0,0,0,0,1,1};
dice4[]={0,0,1,1,1,1};
dice5[]={0,1,1,1,1,1};
dice6[]={0,0,0,0,0,1};

diceQ={1,0,0,1,1,0};
```

So... I am trying to match the indices for diceQ. The match in this test case would be:

```
dice1[2],dice2[2],dice3[2],dice4[2],dice5[2],dice6[2]
```

Comment: these are int array's - just a toy example for a much larger data set. but, also looking for data conversion suggestions!

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you mean by "trying to match the indices"?

Answer (score 0):

In standard Java environment (J2SE) you can use java.util.Arrays.equals(int[], int[]) for one dimension array.